# How do I stop supervisord from stripping colors from the log output of my Node.js server?

Tags: linux, node.js, logging, supervisord

I am using supervisord to manage my Node.js server (ensure it reboots in the event of a crash and send a crash alert email).  However, I am finding that if I run my `app.js` process through supervisord, the outputs to my `server.log` and to `console` are both stripped of color.  I am using the [Winston library](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) to handle my logging.  I have a few examples of output below:

Contents of `server.log` after running through `supervisord`:

```
2015-08-12T20:41:29.203Z - silly: Connected to redis
2015-08-12T20:41:29.206Z - debug: Connected to redis
2015-08-12T20:41:29.206Z - verbose: Connected to redis
2015-08-12T20:41:29.207Z - info: Connected to redis
2015-08-12T20:41:29.207Z - warn: Connected to redis
2015-08-12T20:41:29.207Z - error: Connected to redis
```

Contents of `server.log` after running through shell (`$ node app.js`):

```
2015-08-12T20:41:37.732Z - ^[[35msilly^[[39m: Connected to redis
2015-08-12T20:41:37.737Z - ^[[34mdebug^[[39m: Connected to redis
2015-08-12T20:41:37.741Z - ^[[36mverbose^[[39m: Connected to redis
2015-08-12T20:41:37.742Z - ^[[32minfo^[[39m: Connected to redis
2015-08-12T20:41:37.742Z - ^[[33mwarn^[[39m: Connected to redis
2015-08-12T20:41:37.742Z - ^[[31merror^[[39m: Connected to redis
```

I also noticed that if I use `tail` from `supervisorctl` to monitor my Node server, the color is stripped from there as well.  When running it from the shell, I can see color output in the console.

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix this issue?

**EDIT**: since someone asked for my Winston configuration:

```
var winston = require( 'winston' ),
    fs = require( 'fs' ),
    logDir = 'logs', // Or read from a configuration
    logger;

winston.setLevels( winston.config.npm.levels );
winston.addColors( winston.config.npm.colors );

if ( !fs.existsSync( logDir ) ) { 
    // Create the directory if it does not exist
    fs.mkdirSync( logDir );
}
logger = new( winston.Logger )( {
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console( {
            level: 'silly',
            colorize: true
        } ),
        new winston.transports.File( {
            level: 'silly',
            json: false,
            colorize: true,
            filename: logDir + '/server.log',
            maxsize: 1024 * 1024 * 25 // 25MB
        } ) 
    ],  
    exceptionHandlers: [
        new winston.transports.File( {
            filename: 'log/exceptions.log'
        } ) 
    ]   
} );

module.exports = logger;
```

Comment: Your apps are probably detecting that they are not connected to a terminal and are disabling color output because of this.

Comment: You can enforce colors with Winston. Perhaps you should post your Winston configuration code.

Comment: I am enforcing color output with Winston.  I have all levels of logging enabled with `colorize` set to true for both the `File` and `Console` transports.  I added my config above.  The examples of the two outputs are with that configuration, just one is while the process is managed through supervisord and the other is when I just run my app.js file with the `node` command through the shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer to this question on the [Super User Stack Echange](https://superuser.com/a/751809/483303).

To quote it:

> Simply insert `unbuffer` before any command to make it think it is
>   writing to an interactive output even if it is actually piping into
>   another executable. This will preserve color in the case of `ls`.
>
> For example
>
> `unbuffer ls -l --color=auto | tee output.log`
>
> If you don't already have it installed, on Ubuntu and other Debian-ish Linux distributions you can install `unbuffer` by doing.
>
> `sudo apt-get install expect-dev`